# Matching XML attributes not matching in PHP if statement

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to loop though some XML and preform an action if an attribute value did or didn't match the value it had on the previous iteration of the loop.

The incoming data is already sorted by the class.

Here is some sample XML and code

```
<character_list>
    <character id="00001">
        <name first="Name1"/>
        <type class="Class A" classid="1"/>
    </character>
    <character id="00002">
        <name first="Name2"/>
        <type class="Class A" classid="1"/>
    </character>
    <character id="00003">
        <name first="Name3"/>
        <type class="Class B" classid="2"/>
    </character>
    <character id="00004">
        <name first="Name4"/>
        <type class="Class B" classid="2"/>
    </character>
    <character id="00005">
        <name first="Name5"/>
        <type class="Class B" classid="2"/>
    </character>
    <character id="00006">
        <name first="Name6"/>
        <type class="Class C" classid="3"/>
    </character>
    <character id="00007">
        <name first="Name7"/>
        <type class="Class D" classid="4"/>
    </character>
    <character id="00008">
        <name first="Name8"/>
        <type class="Class D" classid="4"/>
    </character>
</character_list>
```

Here is my code

```
<?php
$query = "data.xml";
$xml = file_get_contents($query);

try {
        $dataobj = NEW SimpleXMLElement($xml);
}

catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "Parsing error!  ".$e->getMessage()." in ".basename($e->getFile()).":".$e->getLine()."!";
        exit;
}

$lastclass = 0;

foreach ($dataobj as $xmldata) {

        $currentclass = $xmldata->type['classid'];

        if ($lastclass == $currentclass) {
                echo $xmldata->name['first']." ";
        }
        else
        {
                echo "<br>";
                echo $xmldata->type['class']." - ";
                echo $xmldata->name['first']." ";
        }

        $lastclass = $xmldata->type['classid'];
}


?>
```

Output from the code

```
Class A - Name1 
Class A - Name2 
Class B - Name3 
Class B - Name4 
Class B - Name5 
Class C - Name6 
Class D - Name7 
Class D - Name8
```

Expected output

```
Class A - Name1 Name2 
Class B - Name3 Name4 Name5 
Class C - Name6 
Class D - Name7 Name8
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast values to strings like that:

```
foreach ($dataobj as $xmldata) {

    $currentclass = (string) $xmldata->type['classid'];

    if ($lastclass == $currentclass) {
            echo $xmldata->name['first']." ";
    }
    else
    {
            echo "<br>";
            echo $xmldata->type['class']." - ";
            echo $xmldata->name['first']." ";
    }

    $lastclass = (string) $xmldata->type['classid'];
}
```

Without casting you are comparing simplexml objects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the incoming data is not sorted, as you shouldn't rely on physical ordering in xml anyway, then instead of printing straight away as you process instead store in a hash or array. Then later print them out in groups as you want.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have added that incoming data is already sorted

Comment: That's semantically wrong for handling xml and bound to be a source of errors and problems. If you want xml records in a particular order, perhaps an attribute should be introduced. Otherwise you're "hacking" xml.